# Using in Class Property MemoryStream and IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, idisposable, memorystream

I am creating an excel and powerpoint document using openxml.
As I do not want to create emtpy file, I want to be sure to write the document only when it is complete using my own `Save` methods. It works weel.

Though, during development, when it crashes, it usually block the DLL file for a while. I was thinking that IDisposable was not properly called. Is there a way to define a using in my class properties `_MemStream`?

```
public partial class Presentation
{
  public Pa.PresentationDocument PresentationDoc { get; set; }   //PresentationPart parts
  private MemoryStream _MemStream { get; set; }

  public void Init(string FileName = "NoName")
  {
    //Init stream
    this._MemStream = new MemoryStream();
    this.PresentationDoc = Pa.PresentationDocument.Create(
    this._MemStream, PresentationDocumentType.Presentation);
    // Create the presentation
  }
  public string Save(string path)
  {
    this.PresentationDoc.Close();
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(FileTemp,
    System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
      this._MemStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
    }

    this._MemStream.Flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: `IDisposable` [isn't going to help if your process terminates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34464312/993547).

Comment: This is what I am looking for: Is there a way to use "using" for a class properties, instead of within the method? Like private MemoryStream _MemStream { get; using( set); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adrian says, things are not disposed by magic. So one way to start disposing is to make Presentation implement IDisposable itself and then dispose of your resources there.

For example:

```
public partial class Presentation : IDisposable
{
  public Pa.PresentationDocument PresentationDoc { get; set; }   //PresentationPart parts
  private MemoryStream _MemStream { get; set; }

  public void Init(string FileName = "NoName")
  {
    //Init stream
    this._MemStream = new MemoryStream();
    this.PresentationDoc = Pa.PresentationDocument.Create(
      this._MemStream, PresentationDocumentType.Presentation);
    // Create the presentation
  }
  public string Save(string path)
  {
    this.PresentationDoc.Close();
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(FileTemp,
      System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
      this._MemStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
    }

    this._MemStream.Flush();
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    if(_MemStream != null)
    {
      _MemStream.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think PresentationDoc.Close should be moved in the Dispose method since it's likely to be a dispose method.

Comment: I recall I cannot write the document to a stream if it is not closed. This is why it is in Save. Basically the save methods is the end. Once saved, does this.Dispose would be usefull?

Comment: You should not call dispose inside the instance itself. It will cause exceptions if the caller does not realise and wraps it in a using of their own. Just use the using clause in the caller to dispose. You can always track the validity of save internally to the class and throw an exception if a subsequent save is attempted

Comment: Thx for all ansers! I am doing this. Should dispoable should be used for every heavy class? (I am creating up to 200 pptx ~3mo in this case)

Comment: Your classes should implement IDisposable whenever, at an instance level, they use any unmanaged resources or any managed resources that implement IDisposable.

Answer (score 0):

The `Dispose` method in not called by magic. If your class creates disposable members, then the class itself it should implement the `IDisposable` interface and call the `Dispose` method of those members. If the class creates disposable instances in a method scope, the those instances should call the Dispose method.

So the Presentation should implement the `IDisposable` interface where you dispose the `_MemStream` and possible.

A client which uses the `Presentation` class should call the `Dispose` method, the framework doesn't do this for us.

Comment: Being relatively new to c#, my question was more: I am pretty sure I have to do it, but what is the best way? Thank you

Comment: https://lostechies.com/chrispatterson/2012/11/29/idisposable-done-right/

You don't need to add the finalizer too.